# SecItemCopyMatching returns more SecIdentityRef items than were added using SecItemAdd

Tags: ios, security, ssl, keychain

I am implementing SSL client authentication for our iPhone app and am using the app keychain to store the client identity (certificate + private key).  After adding the items to the keychain, I am getting some unexpected results when using SecItemCopyMatching.  Quick summary:  I add exactly one SecIdentityRef to the keychain, but SecItemCopyMatching finds two afterwards.  Let me start with the facts.

I am running my app on an iPod with iOS 4.3.5.

I have an empty app keychain to start with.

My certificates are all created using openssl and deployed to the iPod via a PKCS#12 file as an email attachment.
The PKCS#12 file contains:

- Client certificate
- Client CA certificate (issuer of the Client certificate)
- Root CA certificate (issuer of the Client CA certificate)
- RSA private key of the client certificate

SecPKCS12Import successfully imports the file and the resulting dictionary has the following content:

- one "identity"
- one "trust"
- one "chain" (CFArray which holds the three certificates mentioned above)

Using SecItemAdd, I successfully add the "identity" to the keychain.

Next, I retrieve the "chain" array from the dictionary and attempt to add the certificates.  In doing so, the first one fails with error errSecDuplicateItem.  I assume this is because the first certificate is the client certificate and that it was already added to the keychain when I added the identity.  The other two certificates are added without error.

Now, if I go back and use SecItemCopyMatching with these key/value pairs...

```
 keys   = {kSecClass, kSecReturnRef, kSecMatchLimit}
 values = {kSecClassIdentity, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecMatchLimitAll}
```

...two identities are returned!  Furthermore, if I retrieve the certificate for each (SecIdentityCopyCertificate) and then the summary (SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary), I see the both identities have the same certificate!

Lastly, when I try to clear the identities from the keychain (SecItemDelete), the first attempt is successful but the second fails with errSecItemNotFound.

It is clear from all the googling I have been doing that there are "issues" with the iOS keychain.  However, I have not seen this reported; nor have I seen anything even remotely related.

So, my questions:

- Am I using SecItemCopyMatching correctly?
- When using SecItemCopyMatching to find identities in the keychain, how does it determine the identities that are present?  Is this dynamic, or strictly based on how many SecIdentityRef items were added?
- could this problem possibly be related to the certificates themselves?  Note that despite this issue, I am still able to retrieve the first identity and certificates in order to respond to didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge.

I can post code and/or certificate dump, if needed.

Thanks in advance,

Ken Cross
Siemens Enterprise Networks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're using `SecItemCopyMatching` correctly.

`SecIdentityRef` items are not actually stored on the keychain; they are generated dynamically for certificates that have an associated private key available. Duplicate identities are indeed strange, and probably indicate a framework issue -- perhaps the framework gets confused by the duplicate in the second set of certificates? (Please do file a bug at bugreport.apple.com!) Does the duplicate identity go away when you restart the app?

On the other hand, duplicate identities won't necessarily lead to any actual problem. If you are worried that you might be using the wrong identity, simply ask `SecItemAdd` to provide a persistent reference to the one it "creates" and use that to retrieve the `SecIdentityRef` when needed.